# Looping over multiple RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, iterator

I currently have the following PHP:

```
$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( __DIR__ . '/tests/phpunit/' );

/**
 * @var SplFileInfo $fileInfo
 */
foreach ( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $directoryIterator ) as $fileInfo ) {
    if ( substr( $fileInfo->getFilename(), -8 ) === 'Test.php' ) {
        $files[] = $fileInfo->getPathname();
    }
}
```

This creates an array with the paths to the files ending with Test.php in /tests/phpunit. Works nice and well. However now I also want to register stuff in /tests/integration. (There are more things in /tests, so I cannot simply go through that whole directory.) I could copy the code, but that’s be lame. So now I'm trying to figure out how to loop over two RecursiveDirectoryIterator instances. Is this possible in a sane way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To iterate over iterators you can use [AppendIterator class.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/appenditerator.append.php)

```
$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( __DIR__ . '/tests/phpunit/' );
$directoryIterator1 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( __DIR__ . '/tests/integration/' );
$iterator = new AppendIterator();
$iterator->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $directoryIterator ));
$iterator->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $directoryIterator1 ));

/**
 * @var SplFileInfo $fileInfo
 */
foreach ($iterator as $fileInfo) {
    if ( substr( $fileInfo->getFilename(), -8 ) === 'Test.php' ) {
        $files[] = $fileInfo->getPathname();
    }
}
```