# PHP multiple directoryiterator paths

Tags: php, recursion, iterator, directory

How can I use multiple directory paths with RecursiveDirectoryIterator?

```
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirpath),
  \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
$iterator->setFlags(\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

foreach($iterator as $path) {
  // Do something
}
```

This is kind of what I want:

```
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator([$dirpath1, $dirpath2]),
  \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
$iterator->setFlags(\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

foreach($iterator as $path) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: You can use AppendIterator. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079881/looping-over-multiple-recursivedirectoryiterator